# new VueJS project - eslint-loader - TypeError: eslint.CLIEngine is not a constructor

Tags: javascript, vue.js, npm, eslint

I'm starting a new `VueJS` project in `WebStorm`. I've created a new `VueJS` project, upgraded `NPM`, added `Vuetify` and after starting the server, it raises this error:

```
 ERROR  Failed to compile with 1 errors                                                                                                                                                                          11:34:19 AM

Module build failed (from ./node_modules/@vue/cli-plugin-eslint/node_modules/eslint-loader/index.js):
TypeError: eslint.CLIEngine is not a constructor
    at Object.module.exports (/home/milano/WebstormProjects/xxx/node_modules/@vue/cli-plugin-eslint/node_modules/eslint-loader/index.js:223:27)
```

How can I fix this? Should I downgrade `eslint`?

Answer (score 0):

ESLint update 2019.1.3 solves this issue. [See this](https://github.com/eslint/eslint/issues/11957#issuecomment-510054928)

You may need to:

- Upgrade your IDE to get the latest version of ESLint
- Or upgrade ESLint
- Alternatively, there is a hack [here](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-38922), which involves updating how es-lint is imported. For example:

  Change

  this.CliEngine = require(this.basicPath + "lib/cli-engine");

  to

  this.CliEngine = require(this.basicPath).CLIEngine;